# How to get the sum of numeric values in an alphanumeric string in a hey Microsoft Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in a cell like:

> Good response -6,RNR -2,No Voice -1

I need to get the sum of only the numbers in the cell. How can I do it in a single formula?

Comment: is there always a '-' before a number ? and is there only ever 3 numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

I use Excel [RegEx Find/Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php), it adds regular expression functionality to Excel.
*(I'm not affiliated with that add-in any way, just an enthusiast user)*

Here you can use formula like this to find and sum all numbers:
 `=SUM(RegExFind(A1,"\d+"))`

Or to consider negative values too:
`=SUM(RegExFind(A1,"[-\d]+"))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided & assuming there will only ever be 3 values to extract and each 1 digit in length,
The below will work for a string in **A2**:

```
=LEFT(SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10),1)+RIGHT(SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10),1)+RIGHT(A2,1)
```

Of course there are a few assumptions I've made here,

If this does not work explain to me in more detail how your data is structured etc and i will try to amend.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is truly as you show it, with the number being preceded by a `<space>`, and followed by a `<comma>` or the end of the string, then you can use the following.

Define a formula and name it `seq_99` where

```
seq_99 refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Then you can use this *array-entered* formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99))))
```

To *array-enter* a formula, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula which you can see in the formula bar.

I assumed the `-` denoted a negative number. It that is not the case, it is trivial to alter the formula to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a small VBA function. Note that the delimiter may be adjusted as shown below.*

```
Function SumNumbers(rngS As Range, Optional strDelim As String = "-") As Double

    Dim xNums As Variant, lngNum As Long
    xNums = Split(rngS, strDelim)

    For lngNum = LBound(xNums) To UBound(xNums) Step 1
        SumNumbers = SumNumbers + Val(xNums(lngNum))
    Next lngNum

End Function
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- Use this Function in the usual way: **=SumNumbers(Cell Address)**.
- If the delimiter is SPACE, then use **strDelim As
  String = " "** in the argument list.
- If the Delimiter is COMMA, then use **strDelim As String =
  ","** in the argument list.

*I hope this helps you.*

Comment: What if the string contains numbers bigger then 9 too? (e.g. "Good response -16,RNR -2,No Voice -1")

Comment: This Function will SUM any number even if the String is, Good response -16,RNR -2,No Voice -1 or Good response -50,RNR -89,No Voice -100.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, just check now I've include Screen Shot with the Answer.